# Getting SQL Server Compact 4.0 Tools CTP2

Tags: asp.net, download, sql-server-ce, webmatrix

I'm currently trying to install the "new" Microsoft WebMatrix Beta 2 (a web programming IDE). I was trying to use Web Platform Installer for this. But it 404's on the SQL Compact 4.0 CPT2 and it's tools. I was able to get the runtime from the Microsoft downloads page but the tools I am not able to find. I can not install WebMatrix because the tools are a prerequisite.

Does anybody know where to get them from now?

Comment: Have you tried a newer version? Maybe the CTP 2 has been superseded.

Comment: Nah, it's the newest (at least I think). Web Platform installer has it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download the SQL Server Compact 4.0 Tools for Visual Studio from [here](http://erikej.blogspot.com/2010/12/visual-studio-tools-for-sql-server.html)

Answer (score 0):

Same situation with me - two options related with SQL CE CTP2 (DB runtime and some tools) can't be loaded but they are prerequisites...

Comment: You can get the server library itself easily. But the tools are hard to find, if not impossible